# laravel redirect на post запрос

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

Пишу api для своего мобильного приложения на laravel. При отправках пост запроса из приложения сервер отвечает редиректом(301) на этот же url, но по GET. Таким образом обрабатываются только GET запросы. Почему редиректит? В чем проблема? Как отключить редирект?

Comment: на какой маршрут обращаетесь? используются ли midleware?

Comment: Скорее всего в routes этот маршрут обозначен по GET пути

Comment: Да. Проблема была в неправильно прописном маршруте. Он не должен кончаться на слеш и обращаться нужно без слеша